# What is best way to create sub domains dynamically by using Java whenever user register?

Tags: java, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, subdomain

I am trying to achieve to create a sub domains whenever user signup and create an account on my site.

```
www.my-domain.com .
```

Then he can access his file from the address

```
www.username.my-domain.com
```

For this we have created A record and enabled Wildcard as well.

By creating A Record with *.my-domain.com with my ip address.

Now from this step onwards we are confused ? 
By using JAVA code how to create sub domain dynamically 
What to do... Can any one suggest us ?

We tried this solution...

1. Set up wildcard DNS for your subdomains (how you do this depends on your DNS server (or service provider)).
   This one done.
2. Configure your HTTP server so that your default virtual host will get everything from the wild carded DNS (how you do this depends on your HTTP server).

I think we have do this one.as well.

1. Pay attention to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in your script.

I am trying to give some idea with  this codes...

You get the equivalent of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] by appending location.pathname andlocation.search:

var request_uri = location.pathname + location.search;

```
function getAbsolutePath() {
02
    var loc = window.location;
03
    var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(0, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);//to get path of current url
04
    return loc.href.substring(0, loc.href.length - ((loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).length - pathName.length));
05
}
```

Can you give some more improvement suggestion... ?

How to proceed further....

Comment: What the...? _Is this...?_ **No?** `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ` This is **PHP** The code quoted is **JavaScript** with an emphasis on **Script** And you want a solution in **Java**? Does not compute. This all sounds like a test of a non fully Turing-test capable chatbot...

Comment: yaa this is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] PHP one.. I got this solution some where after search... But our website is implementing by using JAVA.So can you give suggestion on JAVA ?

Comment: **Java** or **JavaScript**? What framework? So many words, and so little relevant information about the context...

Comment: www.somenamecomehere.wordpress.com Like this we have to show some default error message .. if there is no name on our site with that url name. If it is existed then we have to show users http://somename.wordpress.com/

Comment: Our site is something like this http://www.wix.com/  or www.weebly.com

Comment: Do you have an Apache in front of the Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's in the wrong area, and you don't fully know what you are asking for, this may help:

1. Your DNS must allow (and be set for) wildcards. [DNSMadeEasy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com) works for me for this.
2. Your Apache config needs to be set for wildcard subdomains.
3. PHP will have to create the file/directory structure for each user, or you will need redirect rules in your .htaccess file to change the subdomain to a query string (for PHP to see), so http://username.domain.com will actually try to load http://domain.com/~username or http://domain.com/user.php?q=username

Research `VirtualDocumentRoot` and `ServerAlias` in your httpd.conf file for Apache.

You can also have everything go to the same `DocumentRoot`, then use PHP to find the requested server name (Hint: `$_SERVER`), then provide the proper content.

Really, you need to research this more to see what you can do in your environment. Most hosting companies don't allow wildcard domains (both in their DNS and setup). With your own Apache server, it's possible, but you want to know what you are doing before you try anything, in production or not.

P.S. Java is not Javascript. Parts related to Apache should go to [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com) and be tagged for [Apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache2).

Comment: I need in JAVA NOT PHP Please

Comment: We have enabled Wildcard just by creating A record with *.mydomain.com

Comment: What web server are you using and what programming language are you using on your server-side pages? Java doesn't create subdomains - DNS points to the server, then the server (apache?) needs to be able to handle the subdomains.

Comment: The code you supplied is PHP, not Java.

Comment: We are using JAVA technologies to implement the website. So we have taken VPS and installed Tomcat and Apache then deployed the site....

Comment: Java doesn't create subdomains. Apache handles incoming requests - If your DNS is set up properly, which you said you did, make sure Apache is able to handle randomly named subdomains. Then worry about programming. One step at a time.

Comment: Should I do any changes in Apache ?

Comment: Once Apache is set up and you verify it works for random subdomains, use rewrite rules to map the subdomains to another URL (doesn't matter what lang you are using). Hence http://UserName8328.domain.com would actually request something like http://domain.com/users/UserName8328 from your server. This isn't a programming question yet - You need to figure this out first, then give us details of how your sites works and what you need.

Comment: You should ask that at ServerFault, tagged under Apache2 and Tomcat. This site handles programming only.

Comment: Ok sure Mean while I will create some request on ServerFault.... Thanks a lot for driving me...

Comment: I have created request here... http://serverfault.com/questions/543910/how-to-write-rules-to-for-random-sub-domains-in-apache

Comment: Answer is right. Author is talking about PHP only when it comes to **reading** incoming user request. You can do this in any language.